# CV/resume entry

Tags: loops

I would like to create a "command" that does this for me:

```
\cventry{jobtitle}{organisation}{date}{description}{bulletpoint...}
```

such as:

```
\cventry{Potato peeler}{TESCO}{1999 -- to date}{
Responsible for the peeling of all potatoes}{
Sped-up potato peeling by 15 percent}{
Increased potatoes' smoothness by 20 percent as measured by 2004 customer survey}
```

yielding:

```
\textbf{Potato peeler} \hfill 1999 -- to date \\
TESCO \\
Responsible for the peeling of all potatoes \\
\begin{list2}
  \item Sped-up potato peeling by 15 percent
  \item Increased potatoes' smoothness by 20 percent as measured by 2004 customer survey
\end{list2}
```

Notice the `varargs` nature of the {bulletpoints...} "argument", by that I mean that the "command" could accept just one parameter, two parameters, `n` parameters, and still work precisely as intended.

Please provide a code example.

Optional: in your code, if it's possible in TeX/LaTeX (I don't know), allow creation of a "CV entry" data structure to hold all data pertaining to a single "CV entry" (title, dates, bullet-point array, ...) and an "array"/"list" of such objects so that the latter may be passed to a "lay out CV entry" function, which would simply typeset each "CV entry" in turn, and then layout the "CV entry" according to the spec above".

Thanks a lot for your help, I think I will learn a lot from this answer so I am grateful in advance for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this task, a new environment seems better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\newenvironment{cventry}[4]{%
  \textbf{#1}\hfill#3\par#2\par#4\par%
  \begin{itemize}% or other customized list environment
  }{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cventry}{Potato peeler}{TESCO}{1999 -- to date}%
{Responsible for the peeling of all potatoes}
  \item Sped-up potato peeling by 15 percent
  \item Increased potatoes' smoothness by 20 percent as measured by 2004
    customer survey
\end{cventry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code! I actually agree with you, the idea of using an environment is much superior to my intuition and it's perfect in almost every respect... apart from not dealing at all with the issue of `varargs` parameters or for loops like the `pgffor` ones? I was hoping to learn that more than anything else from my post... could you teach me?

Comment: One problem of this approach is that I may not have any bullet points, no list of `item` entries, and I would like *not* to have the `\begin/end{itemize}` in that case...